# How to retain selected HTML5 radio button value when you navigate through a DataPager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, listviewitem, datapager

I'm trying to create an online questionnaire and this is the front-end of my website

```
 <table>
    <tbody>

        <asp:ListView ID="lvQuestion" runat="server"  OnPagePropertiesChanged="lvQuestion_OnPagePropertiesChanged" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvQuestion_PagePropertiesChanging">
             <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td><%# Eval("theQuestion") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice1") %>" /><%# Eval("Choice1") %></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice2") %>" /><%# Eval("Choice2") %></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice3") %>" /><%# Eval("Choice3") %></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice4") %>" /><%# Eval("Choice4") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
             No data
             </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </tbody>
</table>


    <asp:DataPager ID="lvDataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvQuestion" PageSize="1">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

I have successfully displayed the questions and its choices(using HTML5 radio buttons). However, when the user navigates from Question #1 to Question #2, the selected answer in Question #1 is lost by DataPager. I needed the selected answers to be saved in order to collect all answers using a single submit button.

Comment: you should maintain your states using `Sessions`

Comment: How do I set the selected value of the HTML5 radio buttons using C#?

Comment: i posted answer try that

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `runat='server'` with providing `id` to controls

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice1") %>" id="rdCh1" runat="server" />

<input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice1") %>" id="rdCh2" runat="server" />

<input type="radio" name="choice" value="<%# Eval("Choice1") %>" id="rdCh3" runat="server" />
```

on Code Behind You can get these values by

```
string selvalues=rdCh1.Value.ToString();
```

You have to Find Radio Buttons inside ListView Some what like this on `ItemDataBound`

```
protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton =
            (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rdCh1");



}
```

Comment: I tried this before but it will have an error of "server tag is not well formed." If we also use <asp:RadioButton ... /> it is not allowed to be inside a ListView.

Comment: you can refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Your answer is almost close but your comment lead me to the right answer. You can write the ASP RadioButton as <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" Text='<%# Eval("Choice1") %>' runat="server" />. As you can see, you have to use single quote(') instead of double quotes(") for the Text attribute.

Comment: The new problem arises though. You cannot call out the RadioButton that is placed inside the ListView in the code behind.

Comment: what do you mean by `call out the RadioButton`

Comment: Let's say the ID of the RadioButton is "rb1" and when you try to type rb1 on the code behind, it displays a red squiggly line.

Comment: @TJRiceball Please update your question with what you did now for better understanding